# Stop re-render of route on each time i switch route in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented react router 4 using Switch, now everything I am clicking on Link it's rendering that component related to that route. So

what I want here is that It should render route once and for all subsequent visit to route it just show me pre rendered route.

Comment: That would be a React anti-pattern. What is the issue you are running into? You may be able to solve it using `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Why was this up-voted?